# TableViewCell Delete button position is not changing when the layout changed to RTL in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, arabic, left-to-right

I am working on an English/ Arabic app in which user can change the language with in the app, so that the app layout as well as language will be changed. I am using **autolayout** and it is changing to **rtl** when I change the `AppleLanguages` value in `UserDefaults` to `["ar-AE"]`.

The problem is, tableview layout has been changed to **rtl** and **ltr**. But the delete button is not changing its position(default on right side) at that time. When I restart the app, the change will be reflected i.e. delete button changed to left side. But why it is not changing on run time ??

Comment: its happening on which iOS version?

Comment: @AdnanAsghar iOS 11

Comment: @KaranAlangat Any solution for this??